# Print only parts of string that matches regular expression Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

I have 400 files containing multiple lines. I want to find specific line and extract/print only part of it.

I want to reach line:

```
Full seesion name: T27I5E8_S1_N005_V004
```

And print only:

```
S1_V004
```

I tried with:

```
for filename in os.listdir(data_directory): 
     with open(data_directory + "/" + filename) as file:
        for line in file:
            if re.search(r'([S][\d])|([V][\d]{3})', line):
                    print(line)
```

but it prints out the whole line.
I also tried:

```
  subjID = re.compile(r'([S][\d])|([V][\d]{3})')

for filename in os.listdir(data_directory): 
     with open(data_directory + "/" + filename) as file:
        for line in file:
            print(subjID.findall(line))
```

but the output looks like:

```
  []
[]
[]
[]
[('S1', ''), ('', 'V094')]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[('S1', ''), ('', 'V094')]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: It prints the line due to `print(line)` Try `print( "_".join(re.findall(r'(?<![^_])[SV]\d+(?![^_])', line)) )`

Comment: It only prints out the S part but not V part.

Comment: I am sure [it outputs all you need](https://ideone.com/dUYPqC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
for filename in os.listdir(data_directory): 
  with open(data_directory + "/" + filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
      m = re.findall(r'[SV]\d+', line)
      if len(m):
        print("_".join(m))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/f0lSZo) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uYpQVD/3). With `re.findall`, all matches are found, and if they were, the result is a `_`-concatenated string made of the matched texts.

**Pattern details**

- `[SV]` - `S` or `V`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits

Comment: Stil...it only prints out the S part but not V part.

Comment: @Kuki Then you are not using my code. Try. Show me your code demo if you are sure you are using *my* code.

Comment: I copied and pasted it. Returns me 400 lines of S1/S2. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Kuki Add that exact pasted code in the question. BTW, add `'r'` reading mode to `open`.

Comment: @Kuki Then just use `r'[SV]\d+'`. Your sample string is wrong then, since you showed that the matches are enclosed with `_`s, and that is not the case in your real data.

Comment: @Kuki That is actually **my** code. Please consider removing your duplicate answer and accepting  this answer as this code worked for you.